# Adb doesn't detect device after upgrade to Lollipop (Sony Xperia Z3)

Tags: android, usb, adb, android-5.0-lollipop, android-usb

Just yesterday my adb was working fine and I was developing my app in peace...
Today I updated my xperia z3 to lollipop (auto update from sony)...
And the adb stopped detecting the device (on mac os yosemite).

What I checked so far:
1) I have the latest version of android sdk installed
2) I tried adb kill-server and adb start-server
3) I double checked developer mode is enabled on device
4) I double checked that USB connection is in Mass Storage Mode

Nothing works! Please help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Go to Settings -> Xperia Connectivity -> Usb Connectivity -> Usb connection mode -> Check MTP mode.

Click Revoke USB debugging authorization in Developer option.

And try sudo adb devices.

Comment: Doesn't work :( Although Sony Bridge for Mac does detect the device and said it's connected... Tried with sudo and without sudo, MTP mode... Still nothing. Thanks for advice anyway! Maybe I need to wait for someone who had exactly the same problem...

Comment: Click Revoke USB debugging authorization in Developer option and try it again.

Comment: That does it! Thanks so much!!! Please update your answer and I will accept it. Thanks again.

Comment: Needed to use adb kill-server before running sudo adb devices as well but worked once I did

Comment: Ran into same issue here.  I didn't need to revoke anything, just (re-)enable "USB debugging" in the device's developer options; it seemed to have been disabled by the upgrade.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same Problem on my LG G2 mini. I solved the problem through installing the LG software LG PC Suite on my computer.

**How I did it:**
Open the connectivity settings in the drop-down menu of your device, when your device is connected to your computer. Open the settings in this window (top-right corner). In my case I was able to install the named software on my computer, when choosing the install item.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the device drivers or re install the drivers. Or I think you should upgrade drivers through internet.

Comment: Thanks! I have the latest drivers. It was the "debugging authorisations", please the the other answer. Thanks for your help anyway!